# Spark scala - compare column value with paramether

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

would like to compare dataframe column with value. I tried to to convert value and use `lit()` but without any results. Below I enclose my hardcoded version, but it doesn't sattisfy requirements.

```
object Analyzer {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // my lav used to comare with column
    val minEfficiency: Double = 0.9

    // I would like compare column with declared val
    // here is hardcoded (poor) version
    val metrics = dataframe.withColumn("State",
      when($"Efficiency" >= 0.9, "ok").otherwise("not ok")
    )

  }
}
```

Dataframe information:

```
scala> dataframe.printSchema()
root
 |-- SensorId: integer (nullable = true)
 |--  Efficiency: double (nullable = true)
scala> dataframe.show()
+--------+-----------+
|SensorId| Efficiency|
+--------+-----------+
|       1|      0.356|
|       2|       0.99|
|       3|        1.0|
|       4|      0.256|
|       5|        0.9|
+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: can you add some data and make it clear, could not get what you are asking, do you mean this did not worked? `when($"Efficiency" >= minEfficiency, "ok").otherwise("not ok")`

Comment: How about this? `dataframe.withColumn("State",
          when(col("Efficiency") >= lit(minEfficiency), "ok").otherwise("not ok")` What kind of error message do you get?

Comment: @astro_asz, your solution with col() works perfect! Please add your comment into the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using `col`?

```
dataframe.withColumn("State", when(col("Efficiency") >= lit(minEfficiency), "ok").otherwise("not ok"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like below using `transform`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

val df = Seq(10,0.9,-1,0.3).toDF("Efficiency")
val minEfficiency = 0.9

def withMinEfficiency(minValue: Double)(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  df.withColumn("State", when('Efficiency >= minValue,"Ok").otherwise("Not Ok"))
}

df.transform(withMinEfficiency(minEfficiency)).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----------+------+
|Efficiency|State |
+----------+------+
|10.0      |Ok    |
|0.9       |Ok    |
|-1.0      |Not Ok|
|0.3       |Not Ok|
+----------+------+
```